# Is below function Riemann integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

$f(x) = \begin{cases} 
      \frac{1}{x^2} & \text{for x rational} \\
      -\frac{1}{x^2} & \text{for x irrational} \\ 
   \end{cases}$

Is it integrable from $1$ to $\infty$?

A book says it is, citing the reason that $|f(x)|$ is integrable and any absolutely integrable function is integrable.

But I am having doubt because I feel that for any partition P Upper Darboux Sum and Lower Darboux Sum are negative of each other, and they are non-zero. So, they will not converge to the same limit.

Any help in this regard is appreciated.

Comment: You're right about the upper and lower sums.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not true that Riemann integrability of $|f|$ implies that of $f$. Perhaps the book is talking about Lebesgue integral in which case this implications holds for all measurable functions $f$. This function is not Riemann integrable.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral

Comment: Even for Lebesgue integrals, that statement is false. Consider the indicator function on a non-meassurable set.

Comment: @Arthur  Your function is non-negative.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Easily fixable, though. Multiply by 2, add $1$. If you want to integrate over some unbounded interval, you can also multiply by $\frac1{1+x^2}$ or something too.

Comment: Multiply by $2$ and add $1$?

Comment: Subtract, of course. Apparently I'm not completely present today. Sorry about that.